# I need a virtual audio device which I can loop back to my real audio output on linux

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, gentoo

What I used to have on windows was I had a virtual audio device with the virtual audio cable program. I set the audio output of OBS studio and the audio output of whatever game I play to that virtual sound device and then whatever goes through that sound device is looped back to my real audio output with the virtual audio cable program. This way OBS Studio will only stream the audio of the game I play, and I can hear the game's audio too.

How can I do that on linux? I tried to do it with jack and jack2 but I could not figure out how to add a virtual sound device and loop back the audio from it to my real audio output. I tried to do with pulseaudio too but I only managed to loop back my microphone input to my audio output.

I am not very experienced in this matter. Also pulseaudio is a must for me. So, however it is done, it must be done in a way that it works with pulseaudio.

Comment: You can create a "virtual audio device" on Pulseaudio by adding a null sink, and there are various ways to connect this up. But please edit your question and clarify what you need. From your description, it sounds just like you want to hear the output of OBS studio and the game you play at the same time, which already works under Pulseaudio by using the same physical sink for both. So you probably want something else.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to do it

I made a null-sink device

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink
```

then I listed my audio devices with

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

which resulted in

```
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
name: <null>
```

then I made a combine-sink device using the name of the sound devices from above

```
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink slaves=null,alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

I set OBS Studio to use the null-sink device as audio device
then I changed the game to use the combine-sink device as audio device

Comment: I am not familiar with OBS Studio, but does it possible not use the output device as output device, but instead as **input** device (using the associated `.monitor` source)? If yes, then this construction makes sense (and you should have mentioned this in the question). If no, I don't see what this does compared to OBS Studio and the game using both the physical output device.